# ¿Por qué el texto que esta dentro de un span se encima al verlo desde un dispositivo móvil?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy trabajando en una página que debe ser responsiva. La cuestión es que tengo un texto dentro de una etiqueta `span` y al verlo desde un celular las letras se enciman.

Este es el fragmento del código:

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto; max-width: 1000px;">
  <div>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <span style="font-size: 36px;">
        Este span es un elemento en línea; este fondo se ha coloreado 
        para mostrar el principio y fin de la influencia del elemento en línea
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me gustaría que me pudieran dar una explicación de por qué sucede esto, de antemano les agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, te invito a que hagas [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas como funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Sobre tu pregunta, no logro reproducir el error que mencionas con el código que muestras. Por favor revisa: [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hola y gracias. Al reproducirlo en una computadora utilizando google chrome con las herramientas de desarrollador no se puede visualizar. La situación me sucede cuando lo visualizo desde un celular o una tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguien le sirve les dejo lo que hice para poder resolverlo. 
En un archivo css agregue un line-height para separar el texto. Les dejo el código css que utilice en caso de que se encime el texto en el celular:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:479px), only screen and (max-device-width:479px){
  div div p span {line-height : 40px !important;}
}
```